# Change CellForRow after didSelectRow AKA calling cellForRowAtIndexPath programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

Im currently working on my first "big" project, a currency converter. When i select a row i want every cell to change value of "nan" label to the currency returned from the xmlparse class. But, i don't know how i should call this piece of code from inside the didSelectRow method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSLog(@"doingit");
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        //  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    XMLparse *parse = [[XMLparse alloc]init];
    [parse setcurrencyname:[Datarray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.nameLabel.text = [Datarray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.prepTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.9f",[parse convertionrate]];
   cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

//didselectrow

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath");
    XMLparse *parse = [[XMLparse alloc]init];
    [parse setHowmuchmoney:1];
    [parse setValutanamn1:[Datarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSLog(@"%@",[parse valutanamn1]);
    [parse loadDataFromXML];

    UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Row Selected" message:[Datarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];



    [messageAlert show];

    //call cellForRowAtIndexPath here?

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to do this:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: Fixed by simply writing: [Tableview reloadData]